# Using GCP's Cloud VPN and App Engine to connect to a Digital Ocean database

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

Can I setup a Cloud VPN and have app engine talk to a database of mine on a Digital Ocean server? I was reading the docs here https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options, and it doesn't mention anything about using App Engine to connect to an external database using the Cloud VPN. It just talks about using an on-premise server to connect to one of GCP's services.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i know for sure that you cannot use cloud vpn with app-engine standard. it should be possibile using app-engine flexible. 
on the other side (digital ocean) you will need to setup a vpn endpoint (eg. using strongswan even in your database droplets) to connect with the cloud vpn service.